# How do I solve the Riddler Challenges where the question marks are behind chain link fences?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

There are a few Riddler challenges that involve hitting a question mark with your batarang while you're standing on a pressure plate (the question mark is unlit until you step on it).

The problem is, there are a few that block off access to the question mark with a chain link fence once the pressure plate is activated.

I've tried throwing a remote control batarang away, and then aiming it at the question mark and letting it fly on it's own, and then stepping on the pressure plate when it passes the fence, but most of these challenges involve more than one question mark.

How do I solve these types of challenges?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I recall you can also use explosive gel to trip the switches once they are active. Gel up all the switches then go over and step on the activating switch. Once they are active, detonate the gel and all the switches should go on.

If there are more than 3 switches, you are usually in the position to gel the out of reach ones first, then quick-throw a batarang at the one closest to the pressure plate.

Comment: I never even considered using explosive gel. Silly me. Will test this in the morning and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, in some of these types of challenges,the switches need to be tripped in a certain order after you apply the gel on all of them. You will need to trigger each gel charge individually to do that. These puzzles gave me a lot of problems for quite some time as I didn't even know I could trigger the gel individually.

Comment: Note that there are also some challenges requiring you to step on pressure plates without touching the ground in between (no question marks though).

Comment: @Albort But that has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just sayin'...